# Openstack dashboard stops after some idle time

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player, openstack

I have openstack installed using devstack.

I have that in vmware player in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

To keep it alive I suspend when I want to leave it in the state it is.

It resumes as well when I start VM.

But if I keep it for long time in idle state, dashboard stops working. and it says unable to connect to dashboard.

What is the issue? do openstack services stop if PC is in idle state? if yes, how can I start back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was ubuntu update and upgrade issue. After updating and upgrading this is happening at almost no time. Still in few exceptions it is happening. But they are very rare.